# How does an asterisk `*` work in the string formatting method `.format(*) ` in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, args, string.format

What is the use of `*` in `.format(*)`?
When using it in the format function below `print(new_string.format(*sum_string))` it changes the value of sum_string in the output from 18 to 1
Why does that happen?
I have read the following link about `*args` and `**kwargs` but couldn't understand how does that apply to the `.format()` function

[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

```
sum_string = "18"
new_string = "This is a new string of value {}"

print(new_string.format(sum_string)) #it provides an output of value 18
print(new_string.format(*sum_string)) #it provides an output of value 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the star operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean)

Comment: I disagree with the dupe. OP has quoted a similar question but doesn't understand how format "interprets" this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it has nothing to do with `format`. `*` unpacks the arguments so if there are, say 4 placeholders and 4 elements in your list, then `format` unpacks the args and fills the slots. Example:

```
args = range(4)
print(("{}_"*4).format(*args))
```

prints:

```
0_1_2_3_
```

In your second case:

```
print(new_string.format(*sum_string))
```

the arguments to unpack are the *characters* of the string (the string is seen as an iterable by the argument unpacking), and since there's only one placeholder, only the first character is formatted & printed (and as opposed to warnings you could get with C compilers and `printf`, python doesn't warn you about your list of arguments being too long, it just doesn't use all of them)

With several placeholders you'd witness this:

```
>>> args = "abcd"
>>> print("{}_{}_{}_{}").format(*args))
a_b_c_d
```

Comment: Yep, just for illustration purposes of what you described: `new_string = "This is a new string of value {}{}"` and `new_string.format(*sum_string)` will "work" as then 2 placeholders are present.

Comment: You are right about the unpacking, but `"{}_"*4` has nothing to do with unpacking. It is just string multiplication, so a form of concatenation. `"{}_"*4` is the same as `"{}_" + "{}_" + "{}_" + "{}_"` which is the same as `"{}_{}_{}_{}_"` which is only then handled by `.format` to fill in the slots. What's more, this kind of multiplication can be applied to all objects that can also be concatenated. So `(1,) * 3` will yield `(1, 1, 1)`. A catch to remember is that this kind of concatenation also duplicates the pointers, so you have to be careful with concatenating mutable objects (eg lists).

Comment: I could change that, it was just to generate a formatting string quickly

Comment: Thank you, I was confused about tuple; I thought `(20, 100, 1.0)` might require three different place holders, but now I understand that without specifying the `*` the entire tuple is substituted to only one place holder and to substitute to three distinct place holders, it needs to be unpacked using the `*` or `*args`