# What is asterisk doing here?

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone please explain what's the asterisk and !r doing here?

I just came across this snippet on internet. It's some class called Polynomial that is instantiated with three coefficients. I looked through internet and figured that `__repr__` is a representation, but how exactly does asterisk and !r works in here?

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Polynomial(*{!r})'.format(self.coeffs)
```

Comment: That will raise an error as it is an invalid format specifier. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does an asterisk \`\*\` work in the string formatting method \`.format(\*) \` in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475322/how-does-an-asterisk-work-in-the-string-formatting-method-format-in-p)

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, I copied it correctly. I will just edit my original post to add the entire code if that helps.

Comment: @Selcuk  Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKPlPJyQrt4. It's at exact 12 minutes the person is using it.

Comment: Ok, you seem to have been missing the closing curly brace. After your edit it looks fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, my apologies I missed that.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk has no special meaning there; it simply prints the asterisk character in the formatted string.

`!r` is a [conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) that calls the `.repr()` of the argument. So the resulting string for the format string in your question would be equivalent to the following:

```
'Polynomial(*' + repr(self.coeffs) + ')'
```